# Non zero exit value 129 error in android

Tags: android

I imported a project and now I am having a very hard time with below mentioned error. I googled a lot but could not get any help . Any help?

```
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'git'' finished with non-zero exit value 129
```

**Edit**
I just imported a project and it took time for syncing the project. I did not hit any command. I am importing project in android studio 3

Comment: Some git command failed.. However, it is impossible to help without more details.

Comment: @W0rmH0le I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time, I have solved this problem. I just downloaded Git(for windows) and everything started working. Hope that helps others.